# Help with two-port network parameters problem!

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

[image: Find the hibrid (h) parameters for the circuit]

Help me, please. I im studying circuit analysis and i couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please translate the question into English? Also what don't you understand.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to understand what the h-parameter equations are asking of you.

$$h_{11} = \frac{V_1}{I_1}\bigg\rvert _{V2=0}$$ I.e. short-circuit $V_2$, such that no potential can be developed accross it. Then, find the corresponding voltage and current.